# Preview Pane does not work for Microsoft documents

Tags: windows-10

I have the preview pane on in the file explorer but it will only preview PDF documents it will NOT preview any Microsoft documents (word, excel, etc.)I really hate that we are forced to upgrade when Microsoft hasn't fixed all of its glitches. Windows 7 worked great and I didn't have this issue and many more now that we upgraded to Windows 10. Does anyone know how to fix this preview issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known permissions issue.

Run the following command an an Administrator CMD window:

```
icacls “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15” /grant “*S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)RX”
```

Ref: [Fix Windows 10 Office Preview in File Explorer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/preview-pane-not-working-for-documents-in-windows/e2d4f84e-ed38-441a-ab91-5d78fbb8ea08?msgId=f2cd1aef-da1a-4fc5-9ef8-9f230cfabf5f&page=11)